# decrease macro variable containing date in steps

Tags: sas

I currently using:

```
data _null_;
    do i = 1 to 5;
        temp = -10 * i;
        %let minimum_date = %sysfunc(intnx(day,%sysfunc(today()),temp),date9.);
        PUT temp;
    end;
run;
```

This gives me an error:

```
ERROR: Argument 3 to function INTNX referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is not a number.
```

Any ideas how to fix this please?

PS:

Ultimate aim expressed as pseudo-ish code:

```
data _null_;
  do i = 1 to 5;
        * set minimum_date to today - i*-10;
        minimum_date = intnx('day',today(),i*-10);
        * assign minimum_date to macro variable min_date;
    call symput(min_date,minimum_date);
    * invoke programs that use macro variable;
    %include '/Bla/ChildProgram1.sas';
    %include '/Bla/ChildProgram2.sas';
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Why do you have the macro statement in the middle of your DATA step? It will run before the data step runs. Move it to before the DATA step to avoid confusing yourself.  Then rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: The reason is I have a driver program which uses includes to run the children programs A and B, which in turn use a macro variable. What I intent to do is having a loop inside the driver program that runs the children programs whilst changing the macro variable. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Tom I tried to express what I mentioned earlier as 'pseudo code' - see PS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked SAS to evaluate the string TEMP as if it was a number.  You should just remove the macro code and use normal code.

```
data _null_;
  do i = 1 to 5;
    minimum_date = intnx('day',today(),i*-10);
    format mininum_date date9.;
    put i= minimum_date=;
    call execute(cats('%nrstr(%let) minimum_date=',put(minimum_date,date9),';'));
    call execute("%include '/Bla/ChildProgram1.sas';");
    call execute("%include '/Bla/ChildProgram2.sas';");
  end;
run;
```

Or you could write a macro so that you could use a %DO loop.

```
%macro runall ;
  %let start=%sysfunc(today());
  %do i=1 %to 5;
     %let minimum_date=%sysfunc(intnx(day,&start,-10*&i),date9);
     %include '/Bla/ChildProgram1.sas';
     %include '/Bla/ChildProgram2.sas';
  %end;
%mend runall;
%runall;
```